# Table isn't available even though Flask-SQLAlchemy create_all was called

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to fetch records from my database, but I get

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: driver
```

even though I defined the model and called `db.create_all()`. Why doesn't this work?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()

class Driver(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    result = Driver.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `create_all` before defining your model. Move `create_all` to after all your models are defined or imported.

```
class Driver(db.Model):
    ...

db.create_all()
```